# MySQl - вывод значения

Tags: php, mysql

Доброго всем.
Что-то я совсем mySQL забывать стал с этой работой "программиста"
Вот результат запроса:

```
SELECT `number` FROM `zayavka` ORDER BY `number` DESC LIMIT 1,1
```

Это запрос выдаёт нужную мне циферку.
А при "монтировании" кода в PHP:

```
$point_back = mysql_query("SELECT `number` FROM `zayavka` ORDER BY `number` DESC LIMIT 1,1", $db);
print $point_back;
```

Выдаёт "Resourse id #5", что такое 5 и почему нет моей циферки?

Comment: Потому что в ответе может быть *что угодно* и php возвращает ресурс, с которым надо работать функциями типа `mysql_fetch_assoc`.

Comment: И для справки. phpшный модуль mysql не безопасен и объявлен устаревшим, разработчики настоятельно рекомендуют переходить на mysqli или pdo_mysql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT `number` FROM `zayavka` ORDER BY `number` DESC LIMIT 1,1", $db);
$result = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
if (count($result) > 0) {
    print $result['number'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

А я сделал так. Чем этот вариант хуже\лучше, чем вариант [@likerRr](/users/5625/likerrr)?

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT (`number`) FROM zayavka ORDER BY number DESC LIMIT 1,1", $db);
$point_back = mysql_result ($query,0,'number');
```

Comment: @I_CaR, http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.mysql-result.php#86175